# How to store data what needs to be accessible by all members?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, oop

I have the following problem (just learning OOP style C++): I have 3 classes:

1. app
2. objectManager
3. object

The app class sets up startup variables and creates an instance of objectManager. It tells objectManager to load values from different files and to precalculate some data in a vector what will be required for each object.

My problem is the following: **I would like to use a precalculated vector accessable for each object**. I don't understand how can I possibly access this variable from the objects, as they know absolutely nothing about the manager's instance.

I've read about **singletons** but I have no idea how should I implement it.

I've read about **static data members** but AFAIK it seems that I still have to somehow connect to the objectManager instance, so it doesn't help me.

I've tried **global variables** (I know...), but ended up with compiling errors.

I've tried to put **static variables outside of a class definition** in objectManager.h (is it a global case?), and I ended up with something strange:
I can access the variables from all parts of the program what includes objectManager.h, but it's value is different/uninitialized in different classes.

objectManager.h

```
#pragma once
#include "Object.h"

static int xxxtest;

class objectManager
{
```

objectManager.cpp

```
xxxtest = 123456;
cout << xxxtest << endl;
-> 123456
```

while in object.cpp or app.cpp (after)

```
cout << xxxtest << endl;
-> 0
```

Can you explain to me what is happening here?

**Can you recommend me a simple and clean way of organizing such a program**, while making a precalculated variable accessable to other parts of the program?

Comment: What is the relationship between `object` and `objectManager`? What is the relationship between `object` and `app`?

Comment: app calls one objectmanager (one way), objectmanager creates a lots of objects, objects needs to access this precomputed vector in objectmanager (two way)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Static class variables are in fact the solution.

Static variables in classes need to be declared in the CPP file, right after the include.

Header:

```
class Class {
  static int staticVariable;
  static void staticFunction();
  //...
};
```

CPP:

```
int Class::staticVariable = 5;
```

Do that, and all Object instances have access to the static variable (if it's private) and all members of the entire Program can access it (if it's public) by stating:

```
int Value = Class::staticVariable;
```

I hope this helps shed some light.
Ah yeah, I used the code from http://de.wikibooks.org/wiki/C++-Programmierung:_Statische_Elemente_in_Klassen (Page is in German) as Reference.

To get back to your problem, that would mean:

Header:

```
class objectManager {
    static std::vector<double> Precompiled;
};
```

CPP:

```
std::vector<double> Precompiled;    //Initialized automatically.
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I made it work like this! Do you know why did I have this strange different member initialization when using static outside of function bodies? Was it a global?

Comment: You're very welcome. :)
And yes, static outside of a function...or any variable outside of a function/class definition...is global. And I believe for those, static behaves differently yet again.

Answer (score 0):

Since you only intend to create one `objectManager`, it is a candidate for a singleton or a regular global. As a global, you could define a header file like this:

```
// in object_manager.hpp
class App;
class ObjectManager;
class ObjectManagerImpl;
ObjectManager & objectManager ();
class ObjectManager {
    friend ObjectManager & objectManager ();
    friend class App;
    std::unique_ptr<ObjectManagerImpl> impl_;
    ObjectManager ();
    void read_files (std::string file1, std::string file2);
public:
    std::vector<int> & precomputed ();
    //...
};
```

And in your source file, you could have something like:

```
// in object_manager.cpp

class ObjectManagerImpl {
    friend class ObjectManager;
    std::vector<int> precomputed_;
    //...
};

ObjectManager::ObjectManager () : impl_(new ObjectManagerImpl) {}

void ObjectManager::read_files (std::string file1, std::string file2) {
    //...
}

std::vector<int> & ObjectManager::precomputed () {
    return impl_->precomputed_;
}

//...

ObjectManager & objectManager () {
    static ObjectManager instance;
    return instance;
}
```

Now, in the source file of your `object`, you would include the header file for `objectManager`, and access the `vector` through the accessor.

```
// in object.cpp

//...
    std::vector<int> &precomputed = objectManager().precomputed();
```